# help with $(this).val() toUpperCase()

Tags: jquery

Given:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var str = 'Test';
        //alert(str.toUpperCase());

        $('#stringFinder').keyup(function (e) {
            alert($(this).val()==str.toUpperCase());
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I make $(this).val() all upper case to get a like comparison using contains?

Thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$(this).val()` returns a [String object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp), which means you perform any [String methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) on it, so:

`alert($(this).val().toUpperCase() === str.toUpperCase());`

Comment: Wasn't getting the intellisense in vs2010 after the .val(). I should have just tried it, eh? thanks for the help, rod.

Answer (score 6):

```
 $('#stringFinder').keyup(function (e) {
     alert($(this).val().toUpperCase() == str.toUpperCase());
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $(".solomayus").keypress(function (event) {
      $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
 });
```

**OR**

```
  $('.solomayus').blur(function () {
      $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
  });
```

Comment: Good point.  val may return a string object, but not by ref.  You have to set it!